# numpy fix issue with memory utilization MemoryError not using all available 120gb of RAM but still throwing an error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reusing a script on using keras to train a text generation model. My attempt was to see how close it can come to mimicking rap lyrics it was given.

The first time doing the lyrics file was about .5 mb in size with around 100k lines of text and it ran ok on my PC.

I later on found a dataset from multiple rap artists from kaggle and populated my txt file with the new content and the size jumped to 307 mb with I believe around 300 million lines of code.

Trying to run this on my PC it always ate up all the available RAM so I decided to run this on the cloud on Google Cloud and I settled with 120 GB VM with an equally high amount of CPU's.

Here's the code of up to where it crashes

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import io

path = 'lyrics.txt'
with io.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()
print('corpus length:', len(text))

chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
print('total chars:', len(chars))
char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

# cut the text in semi-redundant sequences of maxlen characters
maxlen = 40
step = 3
sentences = []
next_chars = []
for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
    sentences.append(text[i: i + maxlen])
    next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])
print('nb sequences:', len(sentences))

print('Vectorization...')
x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
```

The model starts to load but crashes with this error

```
muiruri_samuel@instance-1:~/rap-generator$ python char_lstm_new.py 
Using TensorFlow backend.
corpus length: 306514394
total chars: 359
nb sequences: 102171418
Vectorization...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "char_lstm_new.py", line 44, in <module>
    x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
MemoryError
```

I've been observing the RAM usage with htop and where it crashes fluctuates from 20-60 GB and it always crashes before it exhausts the available RAM.

Is there a way to fix this bug and/or optimize the code given the dataset is really RAM hungry.

Comment: `sentences`,  `char_indices`, `indices_char` and `next_chars` appear to be unused (`len(sentences)` is used, but it appears that this number could be computed without creating the list).

Comment: @snakecharmerb there's code that follows that does use this, the reason I didn't share that part is it crashes before it reaches this point.

Comment: I expect the premature creation of these data structures isn't the root cause, which is why I'm commenting, not answering.  But it might not hurt to defer creation (and hence memory consumption) until after the offending line, just to be sure.

Comment: here's the complete code: https://github.com/Six-wars/rap-generator/blob/master/char_lstm.py

Comment: @ead I don't know how much memory it would take (not conversant with the math to calculate this) there is though 120GB of ram available and from using htop it doesn't exhaust it before it crashes.